# For multiple Receive and/or BeginReceive tasks on the same socket what determines which receives?

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp

A TCP socket, once connected through a listen/accept or a successful Connect attempt, can begin to receive packets by using Receive or BeginReceive.  My question is when you have multiple receive tasks on the same socket (at the same time) what determines which receives the incoming TCP data packets.

When multiple receives are active it seems either may be selected.  Since the receive operations are usually on their own thread/task I presume it might just be the task management process that determines this, but I don't know for sure.

For example:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    int numBytes = socket.Receive(state.byteArray);
});
```

or just

```
socket.Receive(state.byteArray); //blocks if on Main(UI)
```

or

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
     state.byteArray = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];     
     socket.BeginReceive(state.byteArray, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, 
        SocketFlags.None, out state.ser, new  
        AsyncCallback(RelayReceiveCallback), state);

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Receive operations on a socket are processed in the order in which they are queued. You must keep in mind some things though:

- Unless you are synchronizing order between your threads, you don't have control over which thread gets to queue a receive operation first.
- Receive operations will complete in the order in which they were queued. But your own code may or may not get to run in this order. Thread scheduling can cause the completion notifications to be executed out of order.

Basically: it's up to you to make sure you keep track of the buffers you pass to the socket for read operations, which order you've passed those buffers, and ensure that the exact same order is used to process the data you've received, once each of those buffers has data in it as a result of the associated read operation completing.

Frankly, I strongly recommend against issuing multiple concurrent read operations on any given socket. It's a highly advanced scenario, and very easy to get wrong.